# cvFlip() flickers or returns null

Tags: java, opencv, camera, javacv, iplimage

I'm doing a project which involves taking a live camera feed and displaying it on a window for the user.

As the camera image is the wrong way round by default, I'm flipping it using cvFlip (so the computer screen is like a mirror) like so:

```
while (true) 
{   
    IplImage currentImage = grabber.grab();
    cvFlip(currentImage,currentImage, 1);

    // Image then displayed here on the window. 
}
```

This works fine most of the time. However, for a lot of users (mostly on faster PCs), the camera feed flickers violently. Basically an unflipped image is displayed, then a flipped image, then unflipped, over and over.

So I then changed things a bit to detect the problem...

```
while (true) 
{   
    IplImage currentImage = grabber.grab();
    IplImage flippedImage = null;
    cvFlip(currentImage,flippedImage, 1); // l-r = 90_degrees_steps_anti_clockwise
    if(flippedImage == null)
    {
        System.out.println("The flipped image is null");
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The flipped image isn't null");
        continue;
    }
}
```

The flipped image appears to always return null. Why? What am I doing wrong? This is driving me crazy.

If this is an issue with cvFlip(), what other ways are there to flip an IplImage?

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise the flipped image with an empty image rather than NULL before you can store a result in it. Also, you should only create the image once and then re-use the memory for more efficiency. So a better way to do this would be something like below (untested):

```
IplImage current = null;
IplImage flipped = null;

while (true) {
  current = grabber.grab();

  // Initialise the flipped image once the source image information
  // becomes available for the first time.
  if (flipped == null) {
    flipped = cvCreateImage(
      current.cvSize(), current.depth(), current.nChannels()
    );
  }

  cvFlip(current, flipped, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it's amazing, this is the first time I've heard anyone say to initialise the image in this way, yet it seems to work for me now!